# Spawning more Celery tasks into a group within a chain

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I have a Celery task chain that fetches a bunch of documents via HTTP requests and roughly looks like this:

1. Acquire lock for fetch-batch
2. Fetch all items for batch
3. Release lock for fetch-batch

Step 2 is a group that consists of several individual fetch tasks that each process one item in the batch. All the fetches happen in parallel.

Step 3 needs to run after all the tasks in step 2 are completed.

In code, this roughly looks like this:

```
   (acquire_lock.s() |
    celery.group([fetch.s(item) for item in batch]) |
    release_lock.s()).delay()
```

Now, the problem is that a fetched item may contain references to further items that need to be fetched. I would like to fire off these additional fetches as individual tasks as well, so they can be parallelized also.

Is there a way for my `fetch`-task to spawn more tasks in a way that they end up in the same group as the `fetch`-task, i.e. such that my `release_lock`-task doesn't run until all those tasks have completed also?

I tried simply spawning those tasks off independently and having the parent `fetch`-task wait for them using `get()` and that sort-of works, but it ties up one worker per parent task and can thus actually lead to deadlocks, which is probably why calling `get()` from a task is aggressively discouraged by the API and documentation.